# Make .war file for Tomcat from a non-web intellij project

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, war

So I have a regular Intellij java project, now I was asked to create a .war from this so it can be deployed on a tomcat server. However, when I google this, every link assumes I have a web application but I don't. If anyone could help me out with this, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Deploy a "regular java project" in a web application server like tomcat don't have any sense. what do you really want to accomplish?

Comment: Tomcat is a server for webapps. If you don't have a webapp, then you can't deploy it to tomcat. -1

Comment: As I stated in my comment I was told to do this, I knew very well it's normally only done for webapps. I was asking if there was a way to do this without having a webapp... At least read my full post if you plan on downvoting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either deploy the project as a jar, referenced from a web application, or else convert it to a web application.  Tomcat doesn't have a lot of use for java code that isn't called anywhere.